# how to safely truncate text containing html tags with javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string like this:

```
Hello world!<br />this is a new day for us<br /><br />lorem ipsum dolor and more long string here
```

and I need to only show the first 15 characters.. how do I do that? if possible I want to use only vanilla js (no jquery)

I thought of these steps:

1. get rid of the html tags
2. use `substr` to truncate the string

but some people says that using regex `myString.replace(/<[^>]*>?/gm, '');` in javascript to strip html tags is not 100% dependable.. ([link here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/822464)) so now I don't know what to do. any help is appreciated

Comment: You mention JavaScript - are you specifically inside the browser (where you can get it to do the parsing for you), or are you server side with node.js etc?

Comment: in this case the javascript is used with nodejs

Comment: Your sample string contains only `<br />` tags. Is that all there can be in the string ? Or can there be any arbitrary html in there?

Comment: there's only `<br />` tags in the database at the moment.. but if possible I'd like to find a solution that can detect other html tags too in case the feature would include things like adding images

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)

Comment: Have you considered a CSS approach? eg: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

Comment: @Jax-p I actually found the regex formula from that thread, but people say that it's not 100% dependable because some pattern might not be caught..

@NickParsons yes I considered just using `text-overflow` but then the whole string would still be in the DOM, right? wouldn't it become a waste (bandwith-wise)? or am I just over-optimizing?

Comment: Perhaps you could use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-text or https://www.npmjs.com/package/textract